# Featured tab color changed

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, bountied-tab

I just noticed change in color of number in bounty tab in SO. Its not like that I'm big fan of specific color or so, but why mess the consistency.. OR **OKKK JUST ADD MORE COLORS** strategy..

Below in the screen shot..

[image]

- Is this a latest improvement(feature) cause I do remember having blue
  color yesterday.
- Is SO looking forward for more colors....

Cross-checked in Chrome , Firefox...

Comment: It has the wrong CSS class: `"mod-flag-indicator hotbg"` instead of `"bounty-indicator-tab"`. It is blue on the [main page](http://stackoverflow.com/), but brown on [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions) pages.

Comment: somebody changed the RGB value mistakenly ;)

Comment: If only Imgur wasn't blocked...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks, I'm taking a look at this (it's related to a change I made in the way we do tabs).

---

Fixed and it's live now.

As needed by localization, I'm replacing the tabs so we use partial views instead of a hard-coded `StringBuilder`.

Essentially, there are *too many* ways in which we style tab numeric indicators and this got the wrong style.